# Managing different Python scripts with different priority to each

Tags: python-3.x, docker, asynchronous, message-queue, thread-priority

I need to run different Python processes, in a certain order of priority.
Specifically, I have 3 processes, and I need them to work this way:

1. An object detection script, used to locate a person and their position. I need this one to run ***continuously at a high FPS***;
2. another process that, once some conditions are met (when the person is present in the picture in the required position) starts taking screenshots of the image for a certain amount of time;
3. another script that analyzes the screenshots taken by the second one.

I wrote the 3 scripts already and they work fine, but the problem is that process 3 is particularly computationally demanding, and I don't want it to prevent processes 1 and 2 from running smoothly.

My idea is that I could give highest priority to process 1, and send screenshots taken by process 2...to a queue, or something like this.
When the person is not detected in the picture, I could run process 3, and empty the queue as the screenshots are analyzed. However, script 3 should still run with limited resources, so that FPS of script 1 isn't affected too much, and it can still detect if the person enters the picture again.

I'm afraid this might all be a little vague, but could you please suggest me a way or tool I could use to manage the processes this way?
So far, I tried simply saving the screenshots to a folder, but I don't know how to limit the resources usage by process 3.
I'm familiar with the basic usage of Docker, so I was thinking that maybe I could:

- run the processes in different containers, limiting resources allocated to the 3rd one (?);
- use a message broker (Kafka, RabbitMQ?) to store screenshots;

but again, I'm a newbie when it comes to this stuff (speaking of which, I hope I tagged this question correctly), so I don't know if it's an efficient way to to do this (or if it can be done this way, for that matter).

Comment: I am in a similar situation, which I am able to handle to some extent in a mediocre fashion by running the scripts in seperate cmds and then setting different priorities to the processes in windows task manager. But I was curious if you found a good solution and if you did, you could post it as an answer to this question? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi! I forgot about this question, it's been a while! Yes, I fixed the problem by using the multiprocessing python module, and in my case it works quite well :) I'll post my solution asap as an answer, hope it'll be useful.